# Where should 'requires' be kept with regards to rails Automated testing?

Tags: automated-testing, capybara

I've seen both usages: As in say im testing a web app using Capybara/Rspec?

I seen it edited in the spec_helper.rb file:

```
'require capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

for example.

I also see it not placed there and put in each individual test....

Is there a "best practices" for this? Since you can switch between drivers in Capybara does it make sense to keep all the requires in one spot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends largely on:

- whether this is a standalone testing app or part of a rails application.
- if part of a rails application, which rails version was originally / currently used.

In rails applications it's now usually placed in `spec/support/capybara.rb:`, e.g. `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium`